# How to troubleshoot a slow loading website (pinterest clone)?

Tags: mysql, performance, debugging, mariadb, pagespeed

I have a pinterest clone website that used to work normally and that it now takes like 17-20+ seconds to load. This time is spend for getting pins for the main page, but it used to take like a second or so. It is on the same hosting plan, or files are most likely the same, as is the database.

How would I figure out what is going on during these 17-20+ seconds with any of the available tools that are out there on the Net. I can also troubleshoot from within Linux too (root access).

The issue may be related to MySQL / MariaDb connection.

Comment: ERK! I started writing a blog post about diagnosing performance issues and it ended up being a book with 450 odd pages ( https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP-Performance-ebook/dp/B00U7E00H2 ). You're not going to get a definitive answer here.

Comment: It used to work normally, and now it takes like 20 seconds to load the pins on the main page. What could I be looking for here, in order to solve the problem?

Comment: How to find the problem, find out what the problem is? What tools should I use?

Comment: Yea for the `delete` link under your question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries that are so slow.  It _may_ be something as simple as adding a 'composite' index.